# $\min_{a\in \mathbb{R} }E \left[|Z-a|^p\right]$ where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, optimization, expectation

Let $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$ and optimize the following problem. For a given $p>0$
\begin{align}
\min_{a\in \mathbb{R} }E \left[|Z-a|^p\right]
\end{align}

The goal is to find optimal  $a$.

**Things I tried**

W.l.o.g we can transform the problem over $N \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ since

\begin{align}
\min_{a\in \mathbb{R} }E \left[|Z-a|^p\right]=\
\min_{a\in \mathbb{R} }E \left[|N+\mu-a|^p\right]=\min_{b\in \mathbb{R} }E \left[|N-b|^p\right].
\end{align}

Moreover, we know that $E[|N|^p]=\frac{2^{p/2} \Gamma \left( \frac{p+1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{p}} $ and $E[N^p]=0$ for $p$=odd.

So, the problem becomes *kind of manageable* for $p$=even since

\begin{align}
\min_{b\in \mathbb{R} }E \left[|N-b|^p\right]=\min_{b\in \mathbb{R} }E \left[(N-b)^p\right]=\min_{b\in \mathbb{R}} \sum_{n=0}^p{p \choose n}E[N^{p-n}]a^n
\end{align}

and we basically have to find a minimum of a polynomial of order $p$. However, getting a close form solution for large $p$ is not that easy. (At least for me).

My main difficulty is how to approach a general $p>0$?

At first, I thought that the minim was going to be $a=E[N]$ but I don't think this is true.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Let $u(a)=E(|Z-a|^p)$ with $Z$ standard normal and $p\geqslant1$ then $u'(a)=E(v(Z-a))$ with $v(x)=-p\cdot\mathrm{sign}(x)\cdot|x|^{p-1}$. Note that $v$ is decreasing. Since $E(v(Z))=0$ by symmetry, this implies that $E(v(Z-a))$ has the sign of $a$, in particular $u(a)$ is minimal at $a=0$.

Comment: @ Did,  $v$ is decreasing only for $p\ge 1$. Otherwise, I see no flaw in your argument. I thought about arguing with some rearrangement inequality (as $|x|^p$ and the standard normal density are countermonotone), but had no time for this. Anyway, for $p\ge 1$ your argument is certainly simpler than rearrangements.

Comment: So, the conclusion is that if $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$ then for $p \ge 1$ we have that $\min_{z} E[|Z-a|^p]$ is always minimized by the mean $\mu$. Interesting!!!!!  At first I thought that way, but then I change my mind. Is there an intuitive explanation for this?

Comment: @Boby, it depends on what you call intuitive. The rearrangement idea I spoke of in the previous comment is quite intuitive (which does not imply that it works).

Comment: @zhoraster Could you post it whenever you have time?

Comment: Sure, I'll try.

Comment: @Did is switching order of differentiation and expectation trivial in this case?

Comment: @Did never mind I see it.

Comment: @zhoraster The condition that $p\geqslant1$ seems to be written explicitely in my comment hence I fail to understand "Otherwise" in yours. (Unrelated: Please no space between `@` and `user` in `@user`.)